# (sql) i get null result from join 3 tables

Tags: sql

i need result from nama,jabata,gaji,tunj,and biaya but the result i get is like this

```
NAMA    |JABATAN    |GAPOK    |TUNJ     |BIAYA
dede    |staf       |500000   |100000   |-
endang  |staf       |500000   |100000   |-
cici    |manager    |1000000  |250000   |-
adit    |direktur   |2000000  |500000   |-
budi    |direktur   |2000000  |500000   |-
```

the "biaya" doesnt show up, this is my code

```
select p.nama,p.jabatan,g.gapok,g.tunj,r.biaya
from pegawai p
left join gaji g on p.jabatan=g.jabatan 
left join proyek r on p.tugas=r.tugas
group by p.nama,p.jabatan,g.gapok,g.tunj,r.biaya
```

i tried use inner join but the result is "no data found" , where do i get wrong?

this is pegawai table

```
NOPEG   |NAMA   |JABATAN   |TUGAS
1       |adit   |direktur  |a01
2       |budi   |direktur  |b01
3       |cici   |manager   |a02
4       |dede   |staf      |b02
5       |endang |staf      |b03
```

this is gaji table

```
JABATAN  |GAPOK    |TUNJ
direktur |2000000  |500000
manager  |1000000  |250000
staf     |500000   |100000
```

this is proyek table

```
TUGAS   |TGL_AWAL   |TGL_AKHIR  |BIAYA
A01     |01-1-06    |01-3-06    |1000000
A02     |15-2-06    |30-4-06    |2000000
B01     |01-5-06    |15-7-06    |1500000
B02     |15-5-06    |15-7-06    |1000000
B03     |30-5-06    |15-8-06    |1000000
```

Comment: tugas capitalization could be the problem?

Comment: `TUGAS` in pegawai table is not uppercase which different from proyek table `TUGAS`. A01 is not equal to a01.

Comment: also please tag your dbms.

Answer (score 0):

String comparisons are case-sensitive, and the values in the TUGAS columns on the PROYEK and PEGAWAI tables are of differing case. To make this work you can use a function to ensure that their case matches:

```
select p.nama,p.jabatan,g.gapok,g.tunj,r.biaya
from pegawai p
left join gaji g on p.jabatan=g.jabatan 
left join proyek r on LOWER(p.tugas)=LOWER(r.tugas)
group by p.nama,p.jabatan,g.gapok,g.tunj,r.biaya
```

I also suggest replacing the `GROUP BY` clause with a DISTINCT in the field list to be clear about what you're doing:

```
select DISTINCT p.nama,p.jabatan,g.gapok,g.tunj,r.biaya
from pegawai p
left join gaji g on p.jabatan=g.jabatan 
left join proyek r on LOWER(p.tugas)=LOWER(r.tugas)
```

Comment: On SQL Server you can add a collation name next to the equals sign e.g. `p.tugas COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = r.tugas`